# LVM: Fix logical volume to a phyiscal device

Tags: lvm

I'm not sure if what I want to do is necessary nor actually helpful but maybe someone can clarify as I couldn't find a good explanation/solution.

I have a LVM that originally consisted of just a single PV. I have now added a second PV and converted one of the LVs into a mirror using `lvconvert -m1 vg/data`. I would like the other LVs to remain on the original disk and not be spanned over multiple disks. That is in case I later extend one of the LVs they should never be allowed to be stored on two PVs (except if mirrored) with the intention that in case a disk fails I can still recover all the data from the other PV.

Basically I would like to modify the LV to be fixed to a single PV like when you create it using `lvcreate -n fixedToDiskA -L10G vg /dev/sda`.

Question: How do I know if thats already the case, e.g. that the LV will never grow to span data to the second PV and if that's not the case what's the command to do that?

Comment: If you never want an LV to span multiple PVs, then why did you put multiple PVs in the same VG?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Let me just guess: For being able to create a mirrored LV?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica for flexibility - I can't predict right now how my LVs are going to grow in the future, if I were to have multiple VGs then I would potentially have to migrate data from one VG to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the allocation policy. It can be set both for a VG and for an LV. Usually the LVs inherit the one of the VG.

It can be set at VG/LV creation or later with `vgchange`/`lvchange` and shown with `vgs`/`lvs`:

```
$ vgchange --alloc cling storage6

$ vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  storage5       1  10   0 wz--n- 849,36g 288,17g
  storage6       1   5   0 wz--l- 179,33g  23,73g

$ lvs
  LV                 VG           Attr       LSize
  crypto             storage6     -wi-ao---- 150,00g
  test               storage6     -wi-a-----   1,50g
```

In `vgs` output the fifth position in `Attr` shows the setting for the VG, `normal` and `cling` in this case. `cling` is what you want.

In `lvs` the third position of `Attr` is the allocation value for that LV. `i` stands for `inherit` i.e. the VG value.

So the solution for you is to set the value for the VG to `cling`. If you care whether an existing LV is spread over several PVs then check the output of `lvs -o +seg_pe_ranges`.